# ssis how to raise an error in a datapackage that has roll back

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, bins

I have an sql task in a data package that has a connection to a sequence container. In the sql task I have the following:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

TRUNCATE TABLE  foo_Copy
INSERT INTO foo_Copy
SELECT * FROM foo

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRAN

END CATCH
```

The problem is that when an error does happen, "Rollback Tran" is executed and sql server doesn't raise an error, so the sql task doesn't as well and the green connection progresses to the next container.  What is the best way to create a failure, or hinder the next step when doing a rollback within an sql task in a SSIS data package.  Thanks.

Comment: You can always throw your own error in the catch block.

Comment: how, you mean something like select 1\0 lol

Answer (score 0):

You use RAISERROR, see this link: [sql try catch](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150034/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041906-1.shtml)

```
BEGIN CATCH
  -- Whoops, there was an error
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK

  -- Raise an error with the details of the exception
  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

If you're using Sql Server 2012, you can use THROW instead of RAISERROR: [throw error](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/throwing-errors-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: That raises a message, but it won't throw an error that would cause a failure from one ssis object to another.